# call a page manually in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a  Jquery Mobile Page as follows , now what i am trying to do is , in my javascript function  i want to call Page-B when a link inside a Page-A gets clicked , i want to call Page-B in a javascript only not by `<a href="#Page-B" >Click Me</a>` doing this

**Page Code**

```
<html>
<body>
     <div data-role="page" id="Page-A">

          <div data-role="content">
              <a href="#" >Click Me</a>

           </div>

     </div>


     <div data-role="page" id="Page-B">

         <div data-role="content"></div>

     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`changePage()`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) to navigate to another page in jQuery Mobile.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#Page-B", {
  transition: "none" //or any other options
});
```

Comment: My javascript is added in that page only when i try $.mobile.changePage("#Page-B", {
     transition: "slideup"
    }); nothing happens

Comment: Did you add a click handler for the anchor? Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/nuEeJ/

Comment: yeah i add a click handle and its being called too , to get that work i need to pass `Page-A.html#Page-B` , this works but Page-A's control strings wont visible as its switching to `http://www.example.com/Page-A.html#Page-B` rather then `http://www.example.com/Page-A.html?name=john&id=12223#Page-B`

Comment: @Kiliman well your example works like a charm but when i has #Page-B it doesnt move and if i pass some other values with .html then it works dont know why

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the problem you're having? Are Page-A and Page-B separate HTML pages?

Comment: No Page-A and Page-B are not separate its withing the one HTML pages

Comment: Well there is one strange thing , when Page-A first loads from another page  then after if i click over a button then changePage doesnt get fire but when i reload the page-A , chagePage gets fired